# Whey protein consumption leading to Celiac disease?

Tags: diet, nutrition, protein

My age is 21. I am 5' 4" (162 cm) and weighed 42kgs when I started hitting the gym back in the first week of May. A couple weeks later, as recommended by my dietitian, I started consuming the **Dymatize Elite** whey protein in the following doses:

- Half scoop with milk 45 minutes before workout
- Full scoop with water just after workout
- Another half scoop with milk anytime during the day

The scoop size is 36g

However, I've been noticing the following symptoms since then:

- Severe constipation
- Stomach feeling bloated, as if its gonna burst even if I inhale
- Sudden rise in my weight. I now weigh 49kgs
- Rashes on my skin
- A sudden increase in my appetite

I searched the internet to find that these symptoms are of Celiac disease. I want to know if the powder really is the cause of the disease.

Answer (score 1):

First: [celiac disease](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/celiac-disease/basics/definition/con-20030410) is an autoimmune response to consuming gluten which is found in wheat flour and certain other grains.  Whey protein, eggs, casein etc. do not contain any gluten whatsoever.  By definition it can't be celiac disease.  However, your symptoms are consistent with an allergic reaction to something in the ingredients for [Dymatize Elite](http://www.allstarhealth.com/f/dymatize_nutrition-elite_whey_protein_isolate_%28all_natural%29.htm).

The most likely culprit would be the whey protein itself (concentrate still contains a decent amount of lactic acid which many people have problems processing).  I would recommend discontinuing use of whey protein immediately.  Try to get your protein requirements from regular food.

If you still need a supplement, then consider the following alternatives:

- Egg protein (albumen): pretty decent tasting alternative to whey, excellent source of protein.
- Casein: much slower absorption, but typically does not have lactic acid so it should have a much lower incidence of allergic reaction.
- Soy protein: plant based protein is very complete, contains no gluten or lactic acid.  Also compatible with vegetarian and vegan needs.
- 100% Whey isolate: isolate is much more processed than concentrate, and faster absorbing.  Isolate is also more expensive, but enough of the lactic acid should be processed out.

It's very important to understand that protein **supplements** are not required to get strong or increase muscle mass.  They are useful when you need to keep your calories down while maintaining your protein intake.  There are also several alternatives to whey that should not cause any allergic reaction.  While trying to find something that works, I recommend only buying the smallest portion and see how that works for you.  However, before trying another protein go 2 weeks without any supplements so that your body can go back to being normal.

Comment: How highly do you rate hemp protein powder as a whey alternative?

Comment: Check out this series: http://schwarzenegger.com/fitness/post/the-protein-bible-part-1-introduction

Comment: The specific resource reviewing different proteins is: http://schwarzenegger.com/fitness/post/the-protein-bible-part-2-protein-powders